# How to generate conditioned random variables from a density function?

Tags: r, sampling, random-generation, rejection-sampling, quantiles

I want to generate random variables from a distribution function using inverse sampling with the additional condition that the sampling should be conditioned, i.e., random generated variables should be greater or less than a given value.

The inverse of my cdf is :

```
invcdf <- function(y) a2 * log(a1/y - 1) + a3
```

a1,a2 and a3 are parameters.

I used inverse sampling to generate n rv as follows :

```
invcdf(runif(n))
```

Now, the problem is that I want the values generated greater than a value. How should I introduce this condition in random sampling?

When I use this to have value greater than 500 :

```
invcdf(runif(10,500,1e6))
```

I get this error message : Warning message: In log((a0/y) - 1) : NaNs produced
This is due to the fact that R is trying to take the logarithm of a negative number for a high value of y (a1=1).

I already try to repeat the process until having values satsifying my constraints is this way :

```
repeat{
 x=invcdf(runif(1))
 if(x>500){
   break
 }
```

But it tooks a lot of time and sometimes can't provide the value that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. It can be helpful for other users. 
The idea is to repeat the process until having values satsifying my constraints!

```
repeat{
  x=invcdf(runif(1))
  if(x>100){
  break
}
```

The method works for a reasonable number of variables to generate. It is not very efficient if we want to generate a great number of variables.